# Jcarousel NOT working at all though I set it up right

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I followed the instructions to make jcarousel work! but it is not working at all. I would like to be able to click on the two pictures and have them slide ...and by the way , I'm testing it offline locally on my desktop.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/madscore.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/skins/tango/skin.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.jcarousel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#carousel').jcarousel({
        // Configuration goes here
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="sliding-panel">
<div id="carousel">
<ul>
<li> <img src="cube.jpg" /> </li>
<li> <img src="cube.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And Below is the CSS for the id carousel in the file madscore.css

```
sliding-panel
{
position:absolute;
top:290;
left:300;
}

#carousel
 {
 width:5000;
 }

 #carousel ul
 {
 list-style:none;
 width:5000;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 position:relative;
 }

 #carousel li
 {
 display:inline;
 float:left;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first load jQuery and then any plugin which requires jQuery.
Also you are referencing jcarousel twice (minified and normal). 
With that said we will end up with this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: corrected that and the two images are still not sliding when I click on them ..and they are stuck right next to each other ..what else could be wrong ??

Comment: Please add an example on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) or [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com); Did you read the [documentation](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) for the plugin?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/welcome/53003/edit  there it is , I am working with files offline though .. the images won't slide

Comment: I thought of a working example to play with and not a copy of your example... :\